# Вызов отдельного файла .pas из программы Pascal

Tags: pascal, linux

Приветствую сведущих.

Каким образом, можно организовать данный сабж? Т.е у меня есть программка, скажем меню, и вот из этого меню, мне нужно вызывать на запуск файлы .pas или скомпилированный exe из этих пасов. Желательно с примером.

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы *.exe компилировал* .pas нафига тебе это, пользуйся компилятором Pascal.

А чтобы запустить файл есть команда

```
Uses Dos
begin
 Exec(ProgramName, CmdLine);
  // где ProgramName - название программы вместе с путем до ней
  // CmdLine параметры командной строки, если программа может принимать эти самые параметры.
end;
```

и помним что **Exec** это процедура.
    Procedure Exec(Path, CmdLine : String);

Answer (score 2):

На Free Pascal у меня получилось это:

```
    Uses CRT, Windows, ShellAPI;

    Begin

      ClrScr;

// Z5.exe - это у меня одна из задач на Паскале (лежит в каталоге с этой прогой)
      Case WinExec(PChar('Z5.EXE'), SW_ShowNormal) Of
        0: WriteLn('Не хватает памяти или других ресурсов!');
        ERROR_BAD_FORMAT: WriteLn('Неправильный формат исполняемого файла!');
        ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: WriteLn('Не найден указанный файл!');
        ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND: WriteLn('Не найден указанный путь!');
        Else;
      End;

      Repeat Until KeyPressed;

    End.
```

WinExec(PChar('полное имя файла'), как показать окно) - второй параметр имеет 3 значения:

- SW_ShowMaximized - окно развёрнуто
- SW_ShowMinimized - окно свёрнуто
- SW_ShowNormal - обычный вид окна

P. S. На Турбо Паскале это, скорее всего, не прокатит, т. к. Турбо Паскаль уже старый и вряд-ли поддерживает WinAPI.

Comment: Причем тут Free Pascal? Хотя разницы на самом деле никакой, кроме названия процедур.

Comment: Турбо Паскаль у меня это не компилирует - не может найти указанные модули.

Comment: Uses Dos. 
Ну паскаль только с DOS работает.

Comment: Turbo Pascal может и не откомпилирует, а вот Delphi по идее должен (если ClrScr убрать)

Comment: Да, Delphi так скомпилирует (если убрать CRT и все функции из этого модуля).

Comment: Собственно компиляция в вопросе не нужна. Нужно просто вызвать программу.

Comment: Кхм, товарисчи, я сосно кожу на иксах, поэтому там фри паскаль, но это не суть важно, ответы верны, хотя второй будет поудобнее

Comment: @VaLenOK007, в вопросе не было указано что целевая ОС - Linux. Этот ответ будет работать только под Windows.

Comment: Да я уж понял, моя ошибка, забыл сообщить... Иксы уже стали настолько родными, что винда в прошлом)

Comment: тогда вопрос нафига программировать на паскале под *unix? извращенец? :)

Answer (score 0):

Итак. Заходим в файл который надо запустить из меню (pas файл). В Турбо Паскаль 7.0 надо зайти в Compile -> Destination -> Disk. Жмем Save и запускаем или компилируем. Далее
вот такая програмка:

```
Program meny;
Uses crt, dos;
Var a:integer;
Begin
writeln('Enter 1 to start program or 0 to exit');
readln(a);
if a = 1 then exec('Путь к файлу exe') else exit;
```

Но есть одно НО. В Linux как запустить .exe? Win-формат. Я не знаю хорошо linux. И не знаю пойдет ли у тебя прога. И ставь путь к исполняемому файлу в формате Линукса.
Думаю был полезен. Удачи в программировании.